# Раскрасить кнопки меню в разные цвета с помощью QSS

Tags: qt, qss

Есть меню с двумя элементами

```
QMenu pmnu("menu");

QAction action1("element1");
QAction action2("element2");

action1.setObjectName("action1");
action2.setObjectName("action2");

pmnu.addAction(&action1);
pmnu.addAction(&action2);

QMenuBar mnuBar;
mnuBar.addMenu(&pmnu);
mnuBar.show();
```

Нужно сделать фон этих элементов разного цвета. В .qss файле записано:

```
QMenu::item#action1 {background: gray}
QMenu::item#action2 {background: red}
```

Ничего не происходит

Comment: а где .qss файл инициализируется в приложении?

Comment: @magrif `QFile file("style.qss");
 file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
 QString strCSS = QLatin1String(file.readAll());
 app.setStyleSheet(strCSS);`

Comment: инициализируется, просто я в коде только суть оставил

Comment: related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208393/pyqt-qaction-qmenu-color

Answer (score 0):

К `QAction` не получится применять стили, т.к. они работают только для виджетов, а `QAction` - наследник `QObject`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208393/pyqt-qaction-qmenu-color